# Better size aligning?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following two vectors in C++11:

```
vector<unsigned char> left = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // it is meant to represent the number: 123456
vector<unsigned char> right = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // meant to be number: 1234
```

After a function processes them, they become:

```
left = { 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
right = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

Now, I need to complete the shorter one with zeros at the end until they are equal in `size()`. I have thefollowing method:

```
void bigint::process_operands( vector<unsigned char> & left, vector<unsigned char> & right )
{
    size_t left_size = left.size();
    size_t right_size = right.size();

    if( left_size < right_size )
    {
        size_t size_diff = right_size - left_size;

        for( size_t i = 0; i != size_diff; ++i )
            left.push_back( '0' );
    } else if( right_size < left_size )
    {
        size_t size_diff = left_size - right_size;

        for( size_t i = 0; i != size_diff; ++i )
            right.push_back( '0' );
    }
}
```

Is there any better implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
auto sz = std::max(left.size(), right.size());
left.resize(sz, '0');
right.resize(sz, '0');
```

`.resize()` will resize the container to the given size, and fill the new elements (if any) with the given value.

Comment: I am not sure abut its performance, but it compiles...

Comment: @Victor What are you unsure about? It's at least as efficient as (probably more than) using `back_inserter` or `push_back`. If you're worried about `max`, replace it with a conditional (although it's almost guaranteed to get inlined).

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, given that you're using `vector` without namespace qualification (that is, not as `std::vector`), I assume you have a `using namespace std;` in this code. This is generally a bad idea, but especially so in this case. You use `vector<unsigned char> & right` (and `vector<unsigned char> left`), however, there is a `std::right` (and a `std::left`) defined in `<ios>`. This could potentially lead to some very confusing compiler errors.

Using a few tricks from `<algorithm>`, we can shorten the above code considerably.

```
void bigint::process_operands(vector<unsigned char> & left_, vector<unsigned char> & right_)
{
   auto& shorter = (left_.size() < right_.size()) ? left_ : right_;
   std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(shorter), std::abs(left_.size() - right_.size()), '0');
}
```

This is much more terse, but I find that using the standard library actually makes this code easier to read and more clear as to exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 5):

I’d just like to point out a very short version of your own code. It is certainly not as C++ish as a `vector::insert` or `fill_n` solution, but what it does is pretty obvious.

```
void bigint::process_operands( vector<unsigned char> & left, vector<unsigned char> & right )
{
    while (left.size() < right.size())
        left.push_back( '0' );
    while (right.size() < left.size())
        right.push_back( '0' );
}
```